# Sprites optimized for retina display

Tags: iphone, css-sprites, retina-display

I'm building a responsive website so I've been reading about css sprites on mobile devices and iphones. I found [this article](http://brianistech.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/ios-retina-sprites/), I think it's the right tecnique but the explanation could've been better. I ended up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9FcH/

Can somebody tell me if it looks ok on the iphone? I'm not sure about that 50%.
Also, does anyone have a better article?

Comment: No, doesn't look OK. Regular: http://cl.ly/3J0Y2t2y17290t3k0a37 Retina: http://cl.ly/171M0a1P3T1B4533290z

Comment: I wrote the article you linked to above. Your jsfiddle is close but has one problem. You specified the background-size property for the retina sprites; however, the size should actual refer to the size of the non-retina sprites.

Comment: @BrianAntonelli Thanks for the reply and the tutorial! It really helped. If I can make a suggestion you should add a demo or at least a couple of reference images :) It's clear now but for people who aren't familiar with the iphone (like me) I can see how it could be confusing at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `background-size` property you specify for Retine enabled devices, should contain the size of the **non-Retina sprite**, i.e., half the width and half the height of the Retina sprite. It should be the size of the total sprite, so not just the size of a single icon within the sprite.

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/qr5fs/2/

**Screenshot (Retina):** https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIDnE.png

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
        .action {
            background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13823768/masonry/img/test-sprite2x.png);
            -moz-background-size: 153px 64px;
            -o-background-size: 153px 64px;
            -webkit-background-size: 153px 64px;
            background-size: 153px 64px;
        }
}
```

Comment: @Arjan Weird … I haven't done anything to it. By the way, why did you re-upload the screenshot to another image hosting server and replaces the URL? (Just out of curiosity.)

Comment: We'd like the images to be available [in a few months too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with), and when using the Stack Overflow image upload [that's much more certain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com/94286#comment225068_90342)!

Comment: @Arjan Makes sense, didn't knew it was a SE specific hosting service. Good to now, thanks!